# How does CONTENT-AWARE FILL work in Photoshop?

Tags: c#, windows, photoshop, fill

I really enjoy programming in C#. After working with Photoshop CS5 - Content Aware I got insanely curious about the way it works. I tried many ways to find it out myself but the amazing-ness of this new feature has gotten me lost. Can anyone help me ?
So basically I would like to know the ( Formula or Code ) behind this cool feature ...

Comment: yeah, pretty sure there's nobody on here that can give you that code in a short post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The algorithm used in content-aware fill is called PatchMatch; there is a paper as well as some code on this website: http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/index.php

The concept is right there in the paper, but actually implementing it is an entirely different story. You're not going to get the code for it anywhere in the open -- there's a reason why Photoshop costs as much as it does.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had seem the website before but what I really wanna know is that , is it possible to make something like it in C# ?

Comment: @Pedrum: The choice of programming language is irrelevant here; it has more to do with understanding the theory behind it and then converting that into code (in any language).

Comment: i like that ;)
i agree with ya.